# Ubuntu Xubuntu Lubuntu 12.10 and Compiz Compostor

Tags: 12.10, compiz

Where can I find the Compiz compositor and the plug-ins that will work in 12.10 all versions

I see the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompositeManager#Compiz article but it has no mention of anything beyond 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where can I find the Compiz compositor and the plug-ins that will work in 12.10 all versions

Compiz, Compiz Settings Manager and the Compiz Plug-ins are in the Ubuntu repositories, Compiz being installed by default as a matter of fact because Unity runs on it (as a plug in).

Depending on the Ubuntu version you're using the Version of Compiz will vary.

In any case, if you're running another Ubuntu variant (read: non Unity) you won't have Compiz installed by default. If you wish to have it and replace your current Window Manager run this.

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
```

Afterwards run `compiz --replace` so that it replaces your current Window Manager be it, Openbox (Lubuntu), Kwin (Kubuntu), XFWM4 (Xubuntu, Ubuntu Studio, Edubuntu).